# How can i resolve HTTP ERROR 500 in laravel 8 project hosted in namecheap

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, hosting

I hosted my Laravel project on Namecheap but its displaying HTTP ERROR 500, when I complained  to the Namecheap customer service,  they showed me the error log message:

PHP Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method Illuminate\Support\Collection::getArrayableItems() in /home/kroooaux/kroofing/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Collections/Collection.php:31

The project is working perfectly offline with my Xampp but I don't know why it's giving me this error when hosted.

Comment: Maybe php version is not equal to your local php version. Can you check this issue

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I have resolved the issue.
By default, Namecheap PHP version is set to 7.4 and my app needed the latest version 8.1 to work properly, so I changed the version of PHP to 8.1 in my NameCheap Cpanel and it solved the issue.